# Apolle client - Is it possible to subscribe to mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/

Is it possible to have some kind of subscription that whenever a certain mutation is called anywhere the client is being used, we will do some event such as console.log

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the Apollo Link functionality: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/.

Here you are able to inspect each GraphQL query, whether outgoing or incoming. I'd suggest having a read through the documentation to determine how best to utilise it for your use case, as you are able inspect everything - even the query name being used.